# What are potential reason where linux send SIGINT SIGTERM or SIGHUP to a python script that is not user initiated?

Tags: linux, signals, amazon-ec2

I am seeing that my python script in ec2 linux getting terminated for some reason.

I am not sure why and how to debug it.

I tried sending the output of `nohup` to a file

`nohup python my_script.py > myprogram.out 2>&1&`

But I don't see anything output to the file.

What is the usual way to find out who is initiating the singal?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the audit subsystem.

1. Install the auditd daemon
2. Run something like `auditctl -a exit,always -S kill -F pid=XXXX -k kill_syscall` (replace `XXXX` with the PID of your process)
3. Wait for your script to be killed
4. Run `ausearch -i -k kill_syscall`, that will list everything that has been logged with the `kill_syscall` tag